# Wordpress background images not showing - issue with database

Tags: database, image, wordpress, background

There are some background images missing from my site: http://www.test.cwscambodia.org/

These include:

- `arrows.png` (arrows on the right and left of the image slider)
- `sponsor_title.png` (behind the the 'our supporters' text) down the bottom of the home page.
- `sponsor_arrows.png` on each side of the 'our supporters' images at the bottom of the home page
- `search_bg.png` which is background of the search field.

You can see how these images should look on the theme's test site: http://themes.themolitor.com/wpaid/

I have been told by the theme developer and the host that it is database problem in the `wp_options` table. However, I do not know which area to fix.

I have been trying to solve this issue for about 3 weeks so I would be really grateful if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

In the **/wp-content/themes/wpaid/style.css** you link to the folder /images. This folder does not  exists.

#### example

```
.pxs_navigation span.pxs_prev {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -560px;
    background:url(images/arrows.png) no-repeat left top;
}
.pxs_navigation span.pxs_next {
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -560px;
    background:url(images/arrows.png) no-repeat right top;
}
.pxs_navigation span.pxs_prev:hover {background:url(images/arrows.png) no-repeat left bottom;}
.pxs_navigation span.pxs_next:hover {background:url(images/arrows.png) no-repeat right bottom;}
```

In this case you will see that the arrows are linked to **images/arrows.png**, a folder that not exists. The good url link is **/wp-content/themes/wpaid/images/arrows.png**

That is the problem why you dont see all the backgrounds on your website. You can use a replace function in a text editor to change them all in one time.